# Gradle resolves "." in dependecies as "/"?

Tags: maven, gradle, groovy

I have following part of the build.gradle:

```
def external = file('../external').absolutePath  

repositories {
    maven {
        url file(external).toURI()
    }
}

dependencies {
    api 'ch.qos.cal10n:cal10n-api:0.7.7'
}
```

Third-party library that my project uses is stored in the `../external/ch.qos.cal10n/cal10n-api/0.0.7/(.jar and .pom)`.

However when running `gradle build` I got following:

```
Execution failed for task ':compileJava'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':compileClasspath'.
   > Could not find ch.1qos.cal10n:cal10n-api:0.7.7.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - file:/home/a/b/external/ch/1qos/cal10n/cal10n-api/0.7.7/cal10n-api-0.7.7.pom
```

Why `/home/a/b/external/ch/1qos/cal10n/cal10n-api/0.7.7/cal10n-api-0.7.7.pom`
and not `/home/a/b/external/ch.1qos.cal10n/cal10n-api/0.7.7/cal10n-api-0.7.7.pom` ?

UPD: .pom and .jar files are downloaded manually from Maven Repository and placed into /home/a/b/external/ch.1qos.cal10n/cal10n-api/0.7.7/`

Comment: Why do you need to use a custom local repository and not just use `mavenCentral()` like it is recommended? This approach will make your build hard to setup on a different machine, as you'll have to replicate the `external` folder as well.

Comment: @LeonardBrünings due to restrictions I only forced to use dependecies aka .jars and .poms that are installed locally on my own computer inside that specific ```external``` directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because that is the layout of local-maven repositories, i.e., the group will be turned to directories. This is in part for performance and usability reasons. Consider the alternative, you'd have one huge directory containing all the groupIds. Working with directories with lots of entries slows down processing a lot. Instead, this layout is hierarchical, reducing the number of files/sub-directories per directory.

So to solve your problem, just change your directory layout accordingly.

`/home/a/b/external/ch.1qos.cal10n/cal10n-api/0.7.7/cal10n-api-0.7.7.pom`

->
`/home/a/b/external/ch/1qos/cal10n/cal10n-api/0.7.7/cal10n-api-0.7.7.pom`